# URL missing in references when using Authordate1 bibliographystyle (bibtex)

Tags: cross-referencing

How do i include the URL text in my references using the bibliographystyle Authordate1?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citep[MBBL2014]

\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{biblo}
\end{document}
```

**biblo.bib**

```
@article{MBBL2014,
author = {Ministeriet for by Bolig og Landdistrikter},
title = {{Matriklens Udvidelse}},
url = {http://grunddata-ejendom-adresse.dk/matriklens_udvidelse},
urldate = {2015-04-20},
year = {2014} }
```

Comment: Please add the contents of your `biblo` file here as well and add a `\cite` command to your document.

Comment: and this is related to `memoir` how?

Comment: The `.bib` content is not intended to be part of the document

Comment: I could post a solution with `biblatex` and `biber`, where the url appears, but the OP uses `bibtex` and `natbib` -- and it does not work.

Comment: Seems to be a real thing (issue): \bibliographystyle{chronology} in my case removes the URLs. What is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `biblatex` solution, which does not work with `natbib` (I am aware of this)

It works with `backend=bibtex` as well...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{filecontents}{mybiblo.bib}
  @article{MBBL2014,
    author = {Ministeriet for by Bolig og Landdistrikter},
    title = {{Matriklens Udvidelse}},
    url = {http://grunddata-ejendom-adresse.dk/matriklens\_udvidelse},
    urldate = {2015-04-20},
    year = {2014} 
  }
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{mybiblo.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{MBBL2014}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]